# Enveloping algebra of affine Lie algebra is (not) noetherian

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras, associative-algebras

I work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=\mathfrak{g}[t,t^{-1}]\oplus\mathbb{C}K\oplus\mathbb{C}D$ the corresponding affine Lie (Kac–Moody) algebra.

Prove or disprove: the enveloping algebra $U\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ is left noetherian.

In the abelian case, it is a well known fact that $\operatorname{Sym}\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ (polynomial ring on $\mathbb{Z}$-many variables) is not left noetherian.

However, in the noncommutative setting, something subtle happens. For example, consider the augmentation ideal $I=\hat{\mathfrak{g}}\cdot U\hat{\mathfrak{g}}=U\hat{\mathfrak{g}}\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$. It is left generated by $\mathfrak{g}$, $t\mathfrak{g},t^{-1}\mathfrak{g}$, $K$ and $D$! Remember
$$(Xt)(Yt)-(Yt)(Xt)=[Xt,Yt]\equiv[X,Y]t^2\bmod K,D$$
and $\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$, so $t^2\mathfrak{g}$ is left generated by $t\mathfrak{g}$, $K$ and $D$. Iterating this construction we can get the whole $I$.

UPDATE As jg1896 pointed out in the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461914), $U\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ is never left noetherian. I still want to ask, if I know $I$ is finitely generated as a two-sided ideal, can I somehow show that $I$ is left finitely generated?

Comment: It is not claimed in [the current answer by jg1896](https://mathoverflow.net/a/461914/14094) that $U\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$ is not left noetherian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is conjectured that over fields $k$ of $0$ characteristic, the universal enveloping algebra of infinite dimensional Lie algebra is never left or right Noetherian.

However, only a few cases of this conjecture are known.

We have the paper [The universal enveloping algebra of the Witt algebra is not noetherian](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2014.05.007) by Sierra and Walton that shows this holds for the Witt algebra, the Virasoro algebra, and the loop algebra $\mathfrak{g} \otimes k[t^\pm]$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algebra, among others.

We also have the paper [Enveloping Algebras of Krichever-Novikov Algebras are not Noetherian](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10468-022-10168-9) by Buzaglo which extends Sierra and Walton's result for all Krichiver-Novikov algebras.

And these two papers summarize that is known so far.

In particular, it is an open conjecture that the enveloping algebra of infinite dimensional Kac-Moody algebras are not left or right Noetherian.

Comment: Thank you! If I know $I$ is finitely generated as a two-sided ideal, can I show that $I$ is left finitely generated?

Comment: I'm confused: why is this answer accepted? It seems to imply non-noetherianity for the affine Lie algebra (central extension of the loop algebra), but not the affine Kac-Moody Lie algebra (semidirect product thereof).

Comment: @YCor the result of the loop algebra does imply the result for affine Lie algebras but does not implies the result for the affine Kac-Moody Lie algebra. The situation is more subtle than it seems.

Comment: @jg1896 Yes this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @YCor ah yes, sorry, I've misread it. What I am saying is that for the affine Kac-Moody algebra it is conjectured that the enveloping algebra is not left/right Noetherian, but the question remains open.

Comment: Yes, your post is clear about this — it is conjectured for general infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. Has the affine KM case been specifically addressed and considered not obvious? (Of course, one should better mod out by $Z$, i.e. consider $D\ltimes$(loop Lie algebra)). Or might it be accessible, e.g., trying to adapt the argument of Sierra-Walton?

Comment: @YCor Yes, the case of affine KM has been considered and nothing is known. I don't see how one can adapt the arguments of Sierra-Walton to this case - but perhaps this can be done. The general conjecture that the enveloping algebras of infinite dimensional Lie algebras are not left/right Noetherian has been explicitly stated more than fifty years ago, and yet almost nothing is known. So this problem can be regarded as a very difficult one.

Comment: @jg1896 In the Sierra-Walton paper, Lemma 1.7 says that for a Lie subalgebra $L'\subset L$, $\mathrm{U}L$ noetherian implies $\mathrm{U}L'$ noetherian. Isn't this enough to conclude?

Comment: @YCor I think you're right.  I wonder why Sierra-Walton did not state this as a corollary, since it is a particular case of extreme relevance.

Comment: @jg1896 you might edit your answer to reflect the above discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The free Lie algebra in two letters L satisfies the conjecture since U(L) is the tensor algebra of a 2-dimensional vector space.
If A is a matrix of indefinite type in Kac classification, then the corresponding Kac-Moody algebra g(A) contains a copy of L. By the Lemma in Sierra-Walton, well-known, g(A) also satisfies the conjecture. For affine Lie algebras, the argument was already sketched.